# Rank of linear transformation from $M_{n×p}(\mathbb{R})$ to $M_{m×p}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let define $J: M_{n×p}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{m×p}(\mathbb{R})$ by

$$J(X)=TX$$ for  $T\in M_{m×n}(\mathbb{R})$ then what is $rank(J)?$

**My attempt**:

(I know that, When $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is multiplication by $m×n$ matrix $A$ then $rank(T)=rank(A)$)

So according to this, I think $rank(J)= rank(T)$ (but here domain and codomain are not usual Euclidean spaces) so I am confused?

Further I am unable to prove that, $rank(J)=rank(T)$

Please help..

Comment: The matrix spaces are still essentially Euclidean spaces. For example the $M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$.

Comment: Sir, but still, how to prove $rank(J)=rank(T) $

Comment: What is the meaning of $T(X)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net sir, just edited. It is just $TX$ product of two matrices.

Comment: **Hint :** Consider first the case where $m=n$ and $T$ is invertible. What is the rank of $J$ in that case ? Do you see why your intuition $rank(J)=rank(T)$ is incorrect ?

Comment: Rats, both matrices in my previous comment were supposed to play the role of $T$. Sorry about that, missus needed my help, and I didn't have time to proofread! Anyway, because $J$ is (in that case) a linear transformation from a $4$-dimensional space to a $4$-dimensional space, the matrix of $J$ should be a $4\times4$-matrix (which is one of the things you absolutely need to sort out before you have a chance at answering this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sir, though we can choose matrix for $T$ but, how can we directly choose the matrix for $J$? Isn't we need to find standard matrix for $J$? (though we can choose $m=n=p=2$. In this case standard basis for $M_{2×2}$ is $\{\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}, \pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr},\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&0\cr},\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}\}$, Using this basis we need to find the standard matrix for $J$. But I think the standard matrix for $J$ obtained in this way does not matches with the matrix for J choosen in your comment)

Comment: I tried to explain that both the matrices I wrote were supposed to be in the role of $T$. That is, two different examples. Deleting that comment because it is apparently confusing. The point was: How many example matrices $T$ have you worked out? That way you would get a better idea about the rank of $J$. The basis you wrote is correct. Now fix a matrix $T$ (of some rank, try out a few). Write down the matrix of $J$ with respect to the correct basis you used. Determine its rank. Do this for a few matrices $T$ and see what you may learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if you have a matrix
$$ X=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1p}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{np}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}| &  & |\\
X_{1} & \cdots & X_{p}\\
| &  & |
\end{pmatrix}$$
where I'm using column vectors, then
$$TX=\begin{pmatrix}| &  & |\\
TX_{1} & \cdots & TX_{p}\\
| &  & |
\end{pmatrix}$$
so if we view $M_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R}) \sim \underbrace{\mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n}_p=(\mathbb{R}^n)^p$ then $J:(\mathbb{R}^n)^p \longrightarrow (\mathbb{R}^m)^p$  functions like $J(X_1,\ldots,X_p)=(TX_1,\ldots,TX_p)$. This made me think of using that $\text{rank}(J)=\dim \text{Im}(J)$. We can let $\{t_1,\ldots,t_r\}$ be a base of $\text{Im}(T)$ ($t_i=Ta_i$ for some $a_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$). Then $r=\text{rank}(T)$ and it's not hard to see that the following collection is a base for $\text{Im}(J)$

$$
(t_1,0,\ldots,0),(t_2,0,\ldots,0),\ldots (t_r,0,\ldots,0)
$$
$$
(0,t_1,0,\ldots,0),(0,t_2,0,\ldots,0),\ldots (0,t_r,0,\ldots,0)
$$
$$\cdots$$
$$
(0,\ldots,0,t_1),(0,\ldots,0,t_2),\ldots (0,\ldots,0,t_r)
$$
which yields $\boxed{\text{rank}(J)=p\cdot r=p\cdot \text{rank}(T)}$.

It shouldn't be hard to generalise this, if you take linear maps $T_i:V_i \longrightarrow W_i$ between finite dimensional vector spacesfor $i=1,\ldots,p$ and then define the map $(T_1\times \cdots \times T_p) :V_1\times \cdots \times V_p \longrightarrow W_1\times \cdots \times W_p$ like $(T_1\times \cdots \times T_p)(v_1,\ldots,v_p)=(T_1v_1,\ldots,T_pv_p)$ then I think It should hold that

$$
\text{rank}(T_1\times \cdots \times T_p)= \text{rank}(T_1)+\cdots +\text{rank}(T_p)
$$

Comment: Sir, first of all thank you so much for answering. Sir I like to know, what are $Im(J)$, $Im(T)$. I think they are given by $$Im(J)=\{(TX_1,TX_2,...,TX_p)| (X_1,X_2,...,X_p)\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^p\}$$ and $Im(T)=\{TX_i|X_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ am I correct? Further, I didn't understand the part" It is not hard to see following collection is a base for $Im(J)$.........

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Your understand of ${\rm Im}(J)$ and ${\rm Im}(T)$ is correct. For the latter question, note that the components of $J(X_1,...,X_p)$ are the $T(X_i)$'s, which lie in ${\rm Im}(T)$ and therefore are linear combinations of $\{t_1,...,t_n\}$. Moreover, you can easily check the linearly independence of the collection using definitions.

Comment: @Mysterygirl is correct, $\text{Im}(f)$ stands for the image of a map $f$. In general, for linear maps and matrices, it holds that their rank equals the dimension of the image $\text{rank}(A)=\dim \text{Im}(A)$. So one can compute the rank of $J$ by giving a base of its image.

Comment: Thank you so much @UCL sir and "Mystery girl mam", After giving it some time, I fully understood it. $(TX_1,TX_2,...,TX_p)=(TX_1,0,...,0)+(0,TX_2,0,...,0)+...+(0,...,TX_p)$. In next step expressing the components $TX_i$'s as linear combination of basis vectors $t_1,t_2,...,t_r$ and then again writing "each p-tuple" as sum of "r" p-tuples we see that, $(TX_1,TX_2,...,TX_p)=k_{11}(t_1,0,...,0)+k_{12}(t_2,0,...,0)+...+k_{1r}(t_r,0,...,0)+k_{21}(0,t_1,0,...,0)+k_{22}(0,t_2,...,0)+...+k_{2r}(0,t_r,0,...,0)+.....+k_{p1}(0,...,0,t_1)+k_{p2}(0,...,0,t_2)+...+k_{pr}(0,...,0,t_r)$.